# Installing GConf on MSYS2

Tags: msys2, mingw-w64, gconf

I try to build some project with MSYS2/MinGW64.
`configure` fails with:

```
checking for gconftool-2... no
configure: error: gconftool-2 executable not found in your path - should be installed with GConf
```

I have found no prebuild distributive at the [home page](https://projects.gnome.org/gconf/).

I have tried to guess a package name for pacman:

```
gconf
gconf2
gconf-devel
mingw-w64-x86_64-gconf
```

and so on.
No success.

Also I have not found GConf package in msys2 [package list](https://bitbucket.org/msys2/mingw-packages/src).

Should I build GConf from sources or is there other way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find `gconf` in the [MINGW-packages repository](https://github.com/AlexPux/MINGW-packages) so we do not have a recipe for building it from source.  You might consider developing such a recipe.  If it works for you, you could submit a pull request and maybe the MSYS2 maintainers will accept it and build it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (and for the right link also). Not sure though that I can do what you have suggested :) MSYS2 and mingw are completely new stuff for me.